# rank out of the total in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am writing a sql script in which I want to get total number of appointments per salesperson then also get how much he rank out of the rest salesperson. e.g Salesperson x has 5 appointment and he rate 4 out of 10 salespersons.

```
**expected results**:
Salesperson x  5   4/10
Salesperson D  6   5/10
Salesperson s  8   7/10
```

Comment: can you post a code that you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [rank()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html)

```
with sales as
(
select Salesperson, count(appointment) appointments
from SalesTable
group by Salesperson
)
select sales.*, rank() over (order by appointments desc) as salesrank
from sales
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thanks for your response. I tried it this way it works:

```
select id,sales_person,"Appointment/Day",rank_for_the_day,"Appointment/Week",rank_for_the_week,"Appointment/Month",
rank_for_the_month,"Appointment/year",rank_for_the_year
from(
select  supplied_id,salesperson,sum(case when appointment_date::date=current_date then 1 else 0 end )"Appointment/Day",
     rank() over (order by sum(case when appointment_date::date=current_date then 1 else 0 end ) desc )||'/'||
    (select sum(case when appointment_date::date=current_date then 1 else 0 end ) from match where date_part( 'year', appointment_date)=2017 
    and appointment_date is not null and date_part('day',appointment_date)=date_part('day',current_date) ) rank_for_the_day,

     sum(case when appointment_date::date between current_date-7 and current_date then 1 else 0 end )"Appointment/Week",
    rank() over (order by sum(case when appointment_date::date between current_date-7 and current_date then 1 else 0 end ) desc)||'/'||
            (select sum(case when appointment_date::date between current_date-7 and current_date then 1 else 0 end )
            from match m where date_part( 'year', appointment_date)=2017 and appointment_date is not null
            and date_part('week',appointment_date)=date_part('week',current_date) ) rank_for_the_week,

    sum(case when date_part('month',appointment_date)=date_part('month',current_date) then 1 else 0 end )"Appointment/Month",
        rank() over (order by sum(case when date_part('month',appointment_date)=date_part('month',current_date) then 1 else 0 end ) desc)||'/'|| 
            (select sum(case when date_part('month',appointment_date)=date_part('month',current_date) then 1 else 0 end )
            from match m where date_part( 'year', appointment_date)=2017 and appointment_date is not null
            and date_part('month',appointment_date)=date_part('month',current_date) ) rank_for_the_month,

        sum(case when date_part('year',appointment_date)=date_part('year',current_date) then 1 else 0 end )"Appointment/year",
    rank() over (order by sum(case when date_part('year',appointment_date)=date_part('year',current_date) then 1 else 0 end ) desc)||'/'||  
    (select sum(case when date_part('year',appointment_date)=date_part('year',current_date) then 1 else 0 end )
            from match m where date_part( 'year', appointment_date)=2017 and appointment_date is not null
            and date_part('year',appointment_date)=date_part('year',current_date) ) rank_for_the_year
from salespersontable
where date_part( 'year', appointment_date)=2017 and appointment_date is not null
group by id,salesperson
)x order by 6 desc
```

However,I would appreciate an efficient way to write this query to minimize resource consumption.